# Problems updating GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am trying to develop an app game that consists of having 12 cards displayed and when you select 3 those get replaced. I build two classes for this, "positions" and "cards". `onCreate()` I make 72 cards and add them onto an `ArrayList` and create 12 positions, this 12 positions have as input a int for whether if selected or not and a Card. The card has as one of it's inputs, `R.drawable.image1`, and in my `ImageAdapter` I put as my `mThumbIds`, `MainActivity.p1.getCard().getImage()`. `p1` is a static instance of position and all the cards are also static. When a position is clicked, it gets selected and when 3 of them are chosen I have:

```
    if (deck.size() > 0) {
        countSel.get(0).setCard(deck.remove(0));
        countSel.get(1).setCard(deck.remove(1));
        countSel.get(2).setCard(deck.remove(2));
        gridview.invalidateViews();
    }
```

Where, deck contains all the cards, and `countSel` only the 3 selected cards. So basically, now the positions in my mThumbIds have new cards and hence new pictures but the image does not update even though the cards do.

Thanks for any help, Here is the rest of my code:

ImageAdapter:

```
package com.example.set;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;



public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public  Integer[] getmThumbIds() {
    return mThumbIds;
}

public  void setmThumbIds(Integer[] mThumbIds) {
    this.mThumbIds = mThumbIds;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return imageView;
}




// references to our images
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        MainActivity.p1.getCard().getImage() , MainActivity.p2.getCard().getImage(), 
        MainActivity.p3.getCard().getImage(),MainActivity.p4.getCard().getImage() , 
        MainActivity.p5.getCard().getImage(), MainActivity.p6.getCard().getImage(),
        MainActivity.p7.getCard().getImage() , MainActivity.p8.getCard().getImage(), 
        MainActivity.p9.getCard().getImage(), MainActivity.p10.getCard().getImage() , 
        MainActivity.p11.getCard().getImage(), MainActivity.p12.getCard().getImage(),
        MainActivity.p13.getCard().getImage() , MainActivity.p14.getCard().getImage(), 
        MainActivity.p15.getCard().getImage()
};
```

}

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="200dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="60dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

And this is the part where I try to refresh the gridview, I will post the rest of the code if anyone thinks the error is there, I'm just having a hard time formatting it properly:

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                choose(p1);
            } else if (position == 1) {
                choose(p2);
            } else if (position == 2) {
                choose(p3);
            } else if (position == 3) {
                choose(p4);
            } else if (position == 4) {
                choose(p5);
            } else if (position == 5) {
                choose(p6);
            } else if (position == 6) {
                choose(p7);
            } else if (position == 7) {
                choose(p8);
            } else if (position == 8) {
                choose(p9);
            } else if (position == 9) {
                choose(p10);
            } else if (position == 10) {
                choose(p11);
            } else if (position == 11) {
                choose(p12);
            } else if (position == 12) {
                choose(p13);
            } else if (position == 13) {
                choose(p14);
            } else if (position == 14) {
                choose(p15);
            } else {
            }
            if (countSel.size() == 3) {
                countSel.get(0).setChosen(0);
                countSel.get(1).setChosen(0);
                countSel.get(2).setChosen(0);
        if (set(countSel.get(1), countSel.get(2), countSel.get(0))) {
                    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got a Set",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    if (deck.size() > 0) {
                    countSel.get(0).setCard(deck.remove(0));
                    countSel.get(1).setCard(deck.remove(1));
                    countSel.get(2).setCard(deck.remove(2));

                    } else {
                        countSel.get(0).setCard(cardnull);
                        countSel.get(1).setCard(cardnull);
                        countSel.get(2).setCard(cardnull);

                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Not A Set" + "remaining" + countSel.size(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                countSel.clear();
            }

            {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "chicken" + "remaining" +countSel.size(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    gridview.invalidateViews();
}

public void choose(Position p) {
    if (p.getChosen() == 0) {
        p.setChosen(1);
        countSel.add(p);

    }

    else if (p.getChosen() == 1) {
        p.setChosen(0);
        countSel.remove(p);
        System.out.println(countSel.size());
    } else
        System.out.println("emo");
}
```

Comment: Are you updating somewhere in your code the `mThumbIds` on which your adapter is based? And don't call `notifyDatasetChanged` from `getView` method.

Comment: I don't know how to answer, but I'm not, it mThumbIds doesn't change, because mThumbsIds takes the image from the card in the position & I still want it to do that, but the card is what changed. Do I still need to update mThumbsIds to itself?